# Tire Swing Frame

Tags: frame, play-structures

I want to build a multi-use frame.  Our plan is to take two 6x6x12 posts, sink them vertically 4 feet down with concrete and put a horizontal 6x6 post on top of the two.  Question is, would that hold a tire swing?  The plan with the frame is to use it both as a hammock frame and when the hammock is not in use, a tire swing.

The kids planning on using the frame are all under ten and under 100 pounds.  Maybe two kids on it at a time, so max 200 pounds.

Think this can be done? Or do I need to use an A frame?

Comment: How do you plan to affix the 6x6 bean to the top of the posts?  That will likely be a weak point.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would feel a lot safer using an A-frame. If your kids are anything like I was at their age, they're going to be swinging with all they've got. Plus, consider the weight of the tire (it's not nothing).

Add all that force together and you would be putting a not inconsiderable amount of force on the posts. Plus, if they swing at an angle, they could skew the structure, putting stress on the joint between the vertical and horizontal.

An A-frame would bear the stresses in the direction of the force better.

Comment: Let me add that I 120% agree that the structure should be an A-frame. One thing to consider is that the legs of the A-frame do not need to be 6x6 timbers. I would think that 4x4 timbers would be more than adequate and quite a bit cheaper as well.

Comment: You really want to also consider adding an angle brace near each top corner of the A-Frame and the horizontal beam so that you do not get sidewise flex and racking of the structure. These can be attached to a cross member that forms the horizontal bar of the A on each side. This would also make a very good place to attach the hammock hooks too.

Comment: Also with an A-frame you don't need to sink the posts into the ground.  Add a cross member between the legs of the A-frame for support and as a attachment point for the hammock.  And concrete piers to anchor the legs.  Legs will not be in the ground and they will last much longer.  To attach the tire swing, one very heavy duty eyelet bolt that goes all the way through the wood and heavy duty washers/nuts to hold it in place.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm going to do the A frame, but I'm having a hard time picturing how the angle brace would go.  I was going to try and find the ez-swing frame brackets, but they aren't sold anywhere near me.  Is there something else comparable?